# Is there a way to handle incorrect, but highly upvoted answers?

Tags: discussion, voting, up-votes, wrong-answers

Consider this question: [How to download and save a file from Internet using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java)

It's a relatively simple question, but the most-upvoted answer (which is accepted) is also wrong. There's a number of comments on the answer (with 30+ upvotes) explaining why the answer is wrong. Somehow it continues to be the most-upvoted answer.

Is there anything that can be done about this? I've heard complains about the "accepted answer" system but this is one where the incorrect answer is the most upvoted, so this is not an issue with the accepted answer system itself.

Comment: Why was this question closed as a duplicate to three questions which do not ask the same thing?

Comment: Duplicates are not based off what is asked but whether or not the answer is applicable.  In this case there are existing questions with answers that answer your question.  An answer to “How to deal with upvoted yet clearly wrong answers”, most certainly answers your question, since your asking for a way to deal with them.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains/4110601#4110601) is now on -12, but once it was on +70. I found it with my [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1346956/largest-reversals-ever-done) SEDE query. Btw, on the first spot, the answer does not seem obviously bad for me (apache will send the multiple headers, I am not sure, what will the browsers do with it).

Comment: @Ramhound That was added as an edit after I asked. There were only three linked questions at the time I posted that comment.

Answer (score 2):

There are many of these answers. Some are also because they're outdated.

If they're really wrong:

- Leave a comment
- Downvote
- Add a correct answer, or if they're already correct answers upvote them.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I see an answer that I believe to be incorrect I downvote it because I believe it to not be useful.

If you have not already downvoted it, then I think you should do so now